# DCOS Troubles with ip-detect script

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I am trying to install Mesosphere 1.10 using the advanced instructions and I have created the following ip-detect script as per the examples:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -o nounset -o errexit -o pipefail
export PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH
MASTER_IP=$(dig +short master.mesos || true)
MASTER_IP=${MASTER_IP:-192.168.24.20}
INTERFACE_IP=$(ip r g ${MASTER_IP} | \
awk -v master_ip=${MASTER_IP} '
BEGIN { ec = 1 }
{
  if($1 == master_ip) {
    print $7
    ec = 0
  } else if($1 == "local") {
    print $6
    ec = 0
  }
  if (ec == 0) exit;
}
END { exit ec }
')
```

Before installing any dcos files, I tested this script on the intended master node and it worked perfectly.
However after installing dcos on this same node, the exact same script returns the following error:

Error: ??? prefix is expected rather than ";;".
awk: fatal: cannot open file `timed' for reading (No such file or directory)

Any ideas why this is happening? Many thanks in advance...

Comment: For the record, this question is being addressed on [users@dcos.io](https://groups.google.com/a/dcos.io/d/msg/users/sqfVAvqi-aU/HrAnAeRABgAJ)

Answer (score 0):

It's because dig is querying remote servers and not finding an entry for "master.mesos". If master.mesos == 192.168.24.20, remove the two MASTER_IP lines and add one MASTER_IP=192.168.24.20.